# My finite FOR LOOP is taking forever to execute

Tags: javascript

Okay so the code below will create all possible combinations from **array** which when added gives **total** and store it in **result**.  I have added a condition to store only the combinations that is of length **room**. Everything is executing fast when the total and room is small (as expected). However with the current values its taking forever to execute the code. I kept the code running for almost a day now but its still executing. My question is - **How to execute this code fast?** or is something wrong with my code...

```
let total = 82132;
let room = 191
let array = [
  2, 4, 6, 8, 20, 12, 14, 16, 18, 40, 22, 24, 26, 28, 60, 32, 34, 36, 38, 80,
  42, 44, 46, 48, 100, 52, 54, 56, 58, 120, 62, 64, 66, 68, 140, 72, 74, 76, 78,
  160, 82, 84, 86, 88, 180, 92, 94, 96, 98, 200, 102, 104, 106, 108, 220, 112,
  114, 116, 118, 240, 122, 124, 126, 128, 260, 132, 134, 136, 138, 280, 142,
  144, 146, 148, 300, 152, 154, 156, 158, 320, 162, 164, 166, 168, 340, 172,
  174, 176, 178, 360, 182, 184, 186, 188, 380, 192, 194, 196, 198, 400, 202,
  204, 206, 208, 420, 212, 214, 216, 218, 440, 222, 224, 226, 228, 460, 232,
  234, 236, 238, 480, 242, 244, 246, 248, 500, 252, 254, 256, 258, 520, 262,
  264, 266, 268, 540, 272, 274, 276, 278, 560, 282, 284, 286, 288, 580, 292,
  294, 296, 298, 600, 302, 304, 306, 308, 620, 312, 314, 316, 318, 640, 322,
  324, 326, 328, 660, 332, 334, 336, 338, 680, 342, 344, 346, 348, 700, 352,
  354, 356, 358, 720, 362, 364, 366, 368, 740, 372, 374, 376, 378, 760, 382,
  384, 386, 388, 780, 392, 394, 396, 398, 800, 402, 404, 406, 408, 820, 412,
  414, 416, 418, 840, 422, 424, 426, 428, 860, 432, 434, 436, 438, 880, 442,
  444, 446, 448, 900, 452, 454, 456, 458, 920, 462, 464, 466, 468, 940, 472,
  474, 476, 478, 960, 482, 484, 486, 488, 980, 492, 494, 496, 498, 1000, 502,
  504, 506, 508, 1020, 512, 514, 516, 518, 1040, 522, 524, 526, 528, 1060, 532,
  534, 536, 538, 1080, 542, 544, 546, 548, 1100, 552, 554, 556, 558, 1120, 562,
  564, 566, 568, 1140, 572, 574, 576, 578, 1160, 582, 584, 586, 588, 1180, 592,
  594, 596, 598, 1200, 602, 604, 606, 608, 1220, 612, 614, 616, 618, 1240, 622,
  624, 626, 628, 1260, 632, 634, 636, 638, 1280, 642, 644, 646, 648, 1300, 652,
  654, 656, 658, 1320, 662, 664, 666, 668, 1340, 672, 674, 676, 678, 1360, 682,
  684, 686, 688, 1380, 692, 694, 696, 698, 1400, 702, 704, 706, 708, 1420, 712,
  714, 716, 718, 1440,
];
function allCombinations(arr, target) {
  var result = [];
  var path = [];
  let n = 0

  function helper(sum, startIndex) {
    if (sum === target && path.length === room) {
      console.log(n++)
      result.push([...path]);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = startIndex; i < arr.length && arr[i] + sum <= target; i++) {
      if (i > startIndex && arr[i] === arr[i - 1]) continue;
      path.push(arr[i]);
      helper(sum + arr[i], i + 1);
      path.pop();
    }
    return;
  }
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  helper(0, 0);
  return result;
}
const result = allCombinations(array, total);
```

Comment: Because of recursive function call `helper`. `helper(sum + arr[i], i + 1);` inside for loop. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I understand right, you're computing combinations of length 191 from a set of 360 numbers. This is a pretty big number (~ 5 + 100 zeroes).

Comment: @georg Yes thats what im trying to do.... Do you have any solution?

Comment: [There is no fast solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Is something wrong with my **helper** function? Im trying to get combinations of length 191 from a set of 360 numbers .

Comment: @Bergi Thats heartbreaking : ) . . . .

Comment: Is it possible to distribute this particular loop to all my CPU cores... since node JS only uses 1 core. I know node JS can be used with multiple core but i dont know about running one loop in multi cores.. Just a thougth